# Programatically define second and third points of a triangle from two points and angles

Tags: c#, geometry, computational-geometry

If I have two points, one being the starting point or vertex (A) and the other being the median point of A, and I also have the three angles, how do I programatically determine points B and C?

[Triangle problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Th9B.jpg)

Comment: What is the median point of A?  It can be interpreted in lots of different ways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: As I'm trying to do this in c#, it is very much about programming, I'd think. @jdweng, the median of point A is the mid point on the side opposite of A. See included diagram.

Comment: Do you know the length of side _a_?

Comment: The problem is too easy.  It becomes more complicated if the triangle is not isosceles, but still solvable.  I didn't see the posted triangle in the link and originally thought the problem was much more complicated.  Having an isosceles triangle the median is perpendicular to the base and divides the base in half.  So you have a point on the base and a slope of the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known vector

```
VA  = a - A
```

Perpendicular vector

```
P = (-VA.Y, VA.X)
```

With needed length:

```
L = (-VA.Y * tan(Pi/12), VA.X * tan(Pi/12))
```

Resulting points

```
B = a + L
C = a - L
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm needing. Thank you!